# Python is crashing on Gst import (windows)

Tags: python, crash, python-import, gstreamer

I'm trying to use Gstreamer 1.2.4 in Python on windows but without any success:
CODE:

```
Line 1: from gi.repository import GObject
Line 2: from gi.repository import Gst
```

The above code crashes python.exe on line 2 ("python.exe has stopped working").
I tested on win XP, win7 ultimate 32bit, win7 ultimate 64bit
Python 2.7 & 3.41.
I'm using "PyGI 3.12.2 AIO" to install Gstreame

UPDATE: This happens only in the last Gstreamer version (1.2.4) Previous versions are working fine.

Comment: Please post the traceback.

Comment: There is no traceback. Python.exe is just crashing with message "python.exe has stopped working"). 
And here is the Window7 log:

Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x53b1ecd8
Faulting module name: _gi_gst.pyd, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x53b89c08
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00001832
Faulting process id: 0x1488
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfaa596eaadd4a
Faulting application path: C:\Python27\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gi\overrides\_gi_gst.pyd
Report Id: bb928138-164c-11e4-abb8-c8bcc8e467ed